# Spurious readiness notification for Select System call

Tags: sockets, select, system-calls

On http://linux.die.net/man/2/select, under BUGS section it is mentioned that the select system call may sometimes spuriously set the FD ready and the subsequent read call will return 0. The text describes one such example (wrong checksum) but I am assuming there would be other reasons too (otherwise they would have fixed this).

Any ideas what could the other causes for Select to return a FD ready spuriously.

and does this apply to other OS'es also. I am currently asking about Linux.

Relevant Section for the link above:

> Under Linux, select() may report a
>   socket file descriptor as "ready for
>   reading", while nevertheless a
>   subsequent read blocks. This could for
>   example happen when data has arrived
>   but upon examination has wrong
>   checksum and is discarded. There may
>   be other circumstances in which a file
>   descriptor is spuriously reported as
>   ready. Thus it may be safer to use
>   O_NONBLOCK on sockets that should not
>   block.

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly an answer, but looking over epoll, these problems seem to be solved for it.

And if I can trust [this message](http://www.spinics.net/lists/netdev/msg151793.html) in netdev, they at least tried to fix it in poll() and select() too (breaking other things).

Thus, this bug doesn't seem to be relevant in foreseeable future.