# select(), recv() and EWOULDBLOCK on non-blocking sockets

Tags: c++, c, sockets

I would like to know if the following scenario is real?!

1. select() (RD) on non-blocking TCP socket says that the socket is ready
2. following recv() would return EWOULDBLOCK despite the call to select()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am aware of an error in a popular desktop operating where `O_NONBLOCK` TCP sockets, particularly those running over the loopback interface, can sometimes return `EAGAIN` from `recv()` after `select()` reports the socket is ready for reading.  In my case, this happens after the other side half-closes the sending stream.

For more details, see the source code for `t_nx.ml` in the NX library of my OCaml Network Application Environment distribution. ([link](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=118173&package_id=278919))

Answer (score 6):

For `recv()` you would get `EAGAIN` rather than `EWOULDBLOCK`, and yes it is possible. Since you have just checked with `select()` then one of two things happened:

- Something else (another thread) has drained the input buffer between `select()` and `recv()`.
- A receive timeout was set on the socket and it expired without data being received.

Comment: In case of timeout, select() returns 0 so I am not worried about it.

Comment: #define EWOULDBLOCK     EAGAIN  /* Operation would block */ -- found on many OSes

Comment: The POSIX.1-2001 allows either errors to be returned when reading on a non-blocking socket (and doesn't require that they have the same value.)

Comment: It's funny that it is defined on many OSes to be the same error code, meaning you can't put it into a switch block for portability.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible, but only in a situation where you have multiple threads/processes trying to read from the same socket.

Comment: Glad to hear that. My application is single threaded so I am fine.

Answer (score 4):

On Linux it's even documented that this can happen, as I read it.

See this question:

[Spurious readiness notification for Select System call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858282/spurious-readiness-notification-for-select-system-call)

Answer (score 1):

Though my application is a single-threaded one, I noticed that the described behavior is not uncommon in RHEL5. Both with TCP and UDP sockets that were set to O_NONBLOCK (the only socket option that is set). select() reports that the socket is ready but the following recv() returns EAGAIN.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's real. Here's one way it can happen:

A future modification to the TCP protocol adds the ability for one side to "revoke" information it sent provided it hasn't been received yet by the other side's application layer. This feature is negotiated on the connection. The other side sends you some data, you get a `select` hit. Before you can call `recv`, the other side "revokes" the data using this new extension. Your `read` gets a "would block" error because no data is available to be read.

The `select` function is a status-reporting function that does not come with future guarantees. Assuming that a hit on `select` now assures that a subsequent operation won't block is as invalid as using any other status-reporting function this way. It's as bad as using `access` to try to ensure a subsequent operation won't fail due to incorrect permissions or using `statfs` to try to ensure a subsequent write won't fail due to a full disk.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in a multithreaded environment where two threads are reading from the socket.  Is this a multithreaded application?

Comment: Even if there's a timeout on the socket rather than just a parameter to `select()`? What if the timeout happens between `select()` and `recv()`?

Comment: In this case you should not see this behaviour.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "timeout on the socket"?

Answer (score -1):

If you do not call any other syscall between select() and recv() on this socket, then recv() will never return EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK.

I don't know what they mean with recv-timeout, however, the POSIX standard does not mention it here so you can be safe calling recv().